# How can I change YouTube Video Quality with MediaElementJs?

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, mediaelement.js

As the Title suggests, I need to change YouTube video Quality with [MediaElementJs](http://www.mediaelementjs.com), I would really appreciate any help I could get.

If anyone would ask: WHERE IS YOUR CODE? The answer would be: I don't know where to start.

Thanks

Comment: Refer this: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_quality. Ideally you should go through documentation properly. Most of the issues will be resolved if you read docs properly

Comment: Hi @Rajesh i know YouTubes api, but i don't know how to call the change in MediaElemetJs, can you give me a small example? Thanks

Comment: SO, nobody can help me out?